# SSL Certificate is Untrusted... sometimes

Tags: security-certificate, apache2

Web Designer I'm working with signed up a new client that needed an SSL certificate. We went to namecheap.com and purchased on from Comodo. Got all the needed files and set it up in ISPConfig.

To test we used Windows 7 running IE8, Firefox 3.6, and Chrome 12, and then on OSX with Firefox 4, Safari 5, and Chrome 13. All of them worked fine.

The client is getting 'This connection is untrusted' in Firefox 4 and 5. Safari works fine on their machine. On my machines and the designer's machines all works with no errors. I had the client forward me the info for the certificate that Firefox has and the fingerprints match up.

I have an old Windows 2000 VM with IE6 and Chrome and those work just fine as well.

Any ideas on what else to check or do?

The server is running Debian 5.0, up-to-date, with Apache 2 and ISPConfig 3.3

Comment: What .crt file did you put in SSL Bundle textarea?

Answer (score 1):

Check the clients machine to make sure their FF is checking your certificate authority... not all browsers 'respect' all authorities & if you have purchased 'cheap' it might be your problem.

-sean

Comment: Also Comodo had some serious issues some months ago, some unauthorized keys where released and FF4+ and Chrome blacklisted them. HOW cheap did you got those keys?

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate bundle was the wrong one for the type of cert that was purchased.

As a side note, while 'namecheap.com' does have cheap in the name, they do offer everything from very inexpensive certs for like $10 all the way on up to EV certs.